# SQL Server SPN's continually being "misplaced"

Tags: sql-server, kerberos

I have an always on cluster of 2 servers.
Every month or two one of them becomes inaccessable, and accessing via sql server management studio gives this error:

[image]

I can remote onto the server using the IP, and the microsoft kerberos tool advises the SPN's have been "misplaced" and need to be created.

I get them created and it works fine, until the next time.

What can cause SPN's to be misplaced?

Comment: I don't think it says that. The actual error message would be _SQL Server cannot authenticate using Kerberos because the Service Principal Name (SPN) is missing, misplaced, or duplicated._ Please [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73540967/edit) your question to include what the error message actually says, as text not screen shot(s). The action you need to take depends on whether it lists `Missing SPNs`, `Misplaced SPNs` or `Duplicate SPNs`, and the causes are different.

Comment: How often are the servers restarted?

Comment: And clarify that you use the same service account on all nodes (ideally this is  GMSA), and whether SQL Server has permission to register its own SPNs (you can see this in the log at startup.  It will always try.)